# POST login route is not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, url-routing, production-environment

I am new to ruby on rails. I am developing an application which has authentication system.
my problem is I am getting error when logging in to the application in production(Heroku). It is working in development.
**Error**
I production after i typing url https://akashpinnaka.herokuapp.com/login,
it is redirecting to https://akashpinnaka.herokuapp.comlogin. I am missing the '/' between root_url and 'login' for POST login. 
**Note**: Working in development environment.
 

**My routes are**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get 'welcome/index'
root 'welcome#index'
resources :articles
resources :projects
resources :users

get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

**Sessions Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to 'login'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/'
  end

end
```

**Sessions#new**

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %> 
  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %> 
  <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when your form can't be saved, you don't redirect. You show the same form, with error explanation.

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      # should've been login_path
      # redirect_to 'login'

      render 'new' # this is better
    end
  end
```

If you are sure that you want to redirect, by all means, go ahead. But supply the correct path :)

Comment: @AkashPinnaka: what do you expect me to reply to this? "too bad"?

Comment: No, as you posted it shows the same form, But it is not. Istead it is throwing up an error :) and thanks for answer.  your answer helps me going better

Comment: It seems that you don't want/need my help in dealing with the error. Good luck to you then, sir :)

Answer (score 2):

You need use `redirect_to '/login'` or `redirect_to login_path` instead of `redirect_to 'login'`

@Sergio Tulentsev's answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "welcome#index"
resources :articles, :projects, :users
resources sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy], path_names: { new: "login", create: "login", destroy: "logout" }
```

Rails has two sets of path helpers - [`_path` and `_url`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)

> `_path`, as we know, is there to provide relative routes (`/path`).
>
> `_url` is there to provide direct routes (`http://domain.com/path`)

Thus, when you have:

`get "/login"` (with leading slash) in your routes, it will almost certainly cause problems with your applications' relative link helpers.

---

As mentioned by `@Sergio Tulentsev`, your `create` method, and the `destroy` method, should be fixed to use the correct path helpers:

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by email: params[:session][:email]
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
       session[:user_id] = @user.id
       redirect_to root_path
    else
       redirect_to login_path
    end
end

def destroy
    ...
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

It's worth taking `@Sergio`'s advice on the `render :new` command too!

Comment: Thanks, u I learnt how to set names for the routes from your answer

Comment: and how to assign multiple resources at the same time :)